# When does 'Reference object' can be reclaimed?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

Now, I met a strange case likes that:

```
public class SoftRefDemo {

     private static List<SoftReference<String>> cache;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int total = 3000000;
         cache = new ArrayList<SoftReference<String>>(total);
         for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
             cache.add(new SoftReference<String>("fafsfsfsdf" + i));
         }

         System.out.println(cache.size());
     }

}
```

I have set the JVM setting:-Xms20m -Xmx40m. When I want to put many of SoftReference to cache, the JVM exit without any promption or exception. Actually, I am doubtful of the action of SoftReference, it's special object for JVM. Could anyone explains what's happen for this program?

**Another two questions:**
1. Does there has extra memory allocation method for those 'special reference instance' in JVM heap?
2. When does those reference instance can be freed when the instance that they pointer to has been freed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not close. I think the user has some genuine question and it is a language issue that is causing lack of clarity. 
@Denny, please try to rephrase the question, your questions are not understandable as currently stated

Comment: I have set the 'total' value from 10000 to 10000000 and take look the execution. When the cache has little String instance, it runs normally, and print the result before JVM exit. Further, more and more instance has been created, JVM executes program take long time and exit without any exception and 'System.out.println(cache.size())' result. In my opinion, JVM does not reach to the last bytecode.

Comment: I created heap dump file for this program. The reason is 'OOM', and most consumed instance is 'SoftReference' (Both space and number).

Comment: If JVM exits without printing an 'OOM' exception stacktrace, that looks like a bug for me.

Comment: Memory leak with OOM(instance number)
java.lang.ref.SoftReference    887,848   
java.lang.String               1321

Comment: @Idolon When the OOM occurs, there always many of SoftReference instance has existing, can you help to explain this case?

Comment: Let's continue our talk in the chat room I've just created at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3805/java-reference-objects

Answer (score 1):

> When the OOM occurs, there always many of SoftReference instance has existing, can you help to explain this case?

Each instance of SoftReference occupies 24 bytes of heap-memory by itself (this is true for 32-bit Sun JVM, and may differ for others VMs). You are trying to store in the list 3'000'000 instances which means you will need at least ~70Mb of heap space just to store the `SoftReference` objects.

`SoftReference` object keeps a "soft reference" to the soft-reachable object (String in your case) and JVM spec guarantees those references will be cleared (i.e. String objects will be garbage collected) before the virtual machine throws an `OutOfMemoryError`. However JVM will **NOT** garbage-collect SoftReference objects since you keep strong references to them from your `cache` list. (So if you need SoftReference object to be removed from the heap - remove it from the `cache` list).

Comment: Is that true? Here is document referred from ibm that to explain the GC process of Reference instance, [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01246/index.html)   Could you help me to find the truth?

Comment: Read carefully `How the garbage collector handles References` section of the mentioned document. It talks about References clearance which doesn't mean Reference object will be garbage collected, but rather means that the reference hold by Soft/WeakReference object will be cleared thus allowing referenced object (in your case String) to be garbage-collected.

Comment: To "find the truth" you need to: 1) Understand the difference between SoftReference object and its referent object; 2) Remember that no Java object could be garbage-collected if at least one strong-reference to it exists.

Comment: hi @Idolon Could you explain the case that there is no any prompting when OOM occurs from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If I run this program with `-mx40m`

```
char[] chars = new char[4096];
List<SoftReference<String>> strings = new ArrayList<SoftReference<String>>();
do {
  strings.add(new SoftReference<String>(new String(chars)));
} while(strings.get(0).get()!=null);
int nulls=0, set=0;
for (SoftReference<String> string : strings) {
  if(string.get() == null) nulls++; else set++;
}
System.out.println("nulls= "+nulls+", was still set= "+set);
```

I get

```
nulls= 4618, was still set= 1
```

One of the problems with WeakReferences and SoftReferences is that they tend to all be cleared at once.

---

Try WeakReference, SoftReferences are only clear if it really has to.  To see them clearer, try creating a large enough array to trigger an OutOfMemoryError.

1. All object are in the heap. Even static fields are wrapped in a pseudo object which is on the heap. (This later behaviour is not defined but it how I have seen it work)
2. The reference instance is freed after it has been discarded (like any other object)

Comment: Discarded?do you means the end of this method? Why JVM exits without any message or exception?

Comment: Discard, as in not reference any more. I am guess the JVM exit without an exception because no error occurred. ;)

Comment: No, there is an error. The last line is not printed and the exit code is 1.

Comment: I have added a working example.  This will work regardless of your maximum memory.

Comment: `> One of the problems with WeakReferences and SoftReferences is that they tend to all be cleared at once`. I think this is very VM-dependent, true for Sun JVM but I observed a different behavior on the Android Dalvik VM.